# Disable buttonset while keeping default style

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, css

Is there a way where I can disable a buttonset in jQuery UI but prevent the buttonsets style from changing to the "grayed out" look when setting the buttons to disabled?

I have tried simply handling the click event of the buttons. IE:

```
 $("#myRadioButton").click(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
 $("#myRadioButton1").click(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

But this doesnt seem to work.

**I am guessing my best bet is to apply the style from the buttonset to non jQuery generated ones and setting them to disabled yeah? Only reason I am wanting to avoid this as in future the ability to click the buttons will be enabled**

Answer (score 0):

The way I have approached this is to create two classes, 'disabled' and 'enabled', and assign them to the button/image as needed. In my click function, I do a check for the class and if there is a 'disabled' class, I return the user.

$('#myRadioButton').click(function(e) { if ($(this).attr('class') == 'disabled' return; });

Comment: I think you may have missed the point $("#myRadioButton").click(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); }); does not work in preventing the radio button from being selected from what I can tell. Am I incorrect?